# ActionFilter equivalent in Asp.net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, action-filter

First off all,I know there is no Action Filter in asp.net core razor pages.But I am searching to find a mechanism that works similar.
What I am trying to achieve is to apply filter based on handler methods.When I try to use pagefilter, it is applied to all methods.Is there any method/way to exclude some handler methods on the same page ?

To clarify question I added some examples.

Here is example pagefilter

```
public class FormValidatorRazor : IAsyncPageFilter
{
    public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals("POST") || context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals("PUT"))
        //code removed for brevity
 }
```

Here is how I apply it to the project

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new FormValidatorRazor());
        //code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Here is example handler methods.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdate(ExModel model)
{
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEdit(ExModel model)
{
}
```

I want my filter to be applied to OnPostUpdate but not to OnPostEdit.How can I achieve that behaviour ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`PageHandlerExecutingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.pagehandlerexecutingcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1) parameter passed in to `OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync` provides everything you need to achieve this. Here's an example that shows the specifics:

```
public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(
    PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
{
    if (context.HandlerMethod?.Name == "Update")
    {
        // Running inside a handler method named "Update".
    }

    // ...
}
```

[`HandlerMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.pagehandlerexecutingcontext.handlermethod?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_PageHandlerExecutingContext_HandlerMethod) is non-`null` when a handler method is being executed. It provides these properties, that might be of interest:

- [`HttpMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.infrastructure.handlermethoddescriptor.httpmethod?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RazorPages_Infrastructure_HandlerMethodDescriptor_HttpMethod), e.g. `PUT`, `POST`
- [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.infrastructure.handlermethoddescriptor.name?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RazorPages_Infrastructure_HandlerMethodDescriptor_Name), e.g. `Edit`, `Update`
- [`MethodInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.infrastructure.handlermethoddescriptor.methodinfo?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RazorPages_Infrastructure_HandlerMethodDescriptor_MethodInfo)

Alternatively, if you'd like to opt-out at the *handler* level, you could use a custom attribute and check for its existence in `OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync`:

```
public class SomePageFilterExcludeAttribute : Attribute { }
```

---

```
[SomePageFilterExclude]
public void OnPostUpdate() { }
```

---

```
public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(
    PageHandlerExecutingContext ctx, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var isHandlerExcluded = ctx.HandlerMethod?.MethodInfo?.
        GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomePageFilterExcludeAttribute), false).Any() == true;

    // ...
}
```